# Throttle Concurrent Build Plugin Not working for the Initial Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-pipelines, multibranch-pipeline

With the intention of Restricting to a single build at any point within a Multi-branch Pipeline Project, I have configured using https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents/#example-3-throttling-of-declarative-pipelines  in my Jenkins file as below:

```
options { 
    disableConcurrentBuilds() 
    throttleJobProperty(
        categories: ['octhrottle'],
        throttleEnabled: true,
        throttleOption: 'category'
    )
 }
```

And configured the same in my Jenkins configuration as well:
[image]

This setup is NOT working as expected whenever I create a new branches in the same repository. Whenever I create new branch, an initial build will run on the newly created branch for which both the newly created branches are running simultaneously. However, it is working as expected when I do subsequent file commits to these branches. Am I missing any additional configs here.

Any help to fix will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is purely a Jenkins issue: Git is not involved in it at all. I snipped the [tag:git] tag. (I'm not a Jenkins expert so I can't add more about this.)

Comment: Agree - Thank you @torek